# jsonpath- Extracting json data using jsonpath

Tags: json, jsonpath

My json data is as follows:

```
"query": {
  "count": 1,
   "url": [
    {
     "execution-start-time": "1"
    },
    {
     "execution-time": "745"
    }
   ],
   "service-time": "1481"
  },
      results": {
       "div": {
        "class": "makers",
        "ul": {
         "li": [
          {
           "a": {
            "href": "nokia_x2_dual_sim-6383.php",
            "img": {
             "src": "Nokia-X2-Dual-SIM.jpg"
            },
            "strong": {
             "br": null,
             "content": "Nokia\nX2 Dual SIM"
            }
           }
          },
          {
           "a": {
            "href": "nokia_xl-6148.php",
            "img": {
             "src": "nokia-xl.jpg",
            },
            "strong": {
             "br": null,
             "content": "Nokia\nXL"
            }
           }
          }
         ]
```

Now I want to extract the `"content"` part from this json data using jsonpath.I am using jsonpath-0.8.0.js for this purpose.

I have tried to parse the json data in the following way:

```
function ParseData(data) {
  var result = jsonPath(data, "$.query.results[*].ul.li[*].strong.content");
  $('#carousel').empty();
  var html = "";
  for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
   // do something
   }
```

and I was expecting to get `Nokia\nX2 Dual SIM` and `Nokia\nXL` as output but this code of mine does not return anything.I cannot understand the problem.

How do I extract the `content` data from this json? please help.

Answer (score 2):

Friends, I finally got the answer to my problem.I used the following code to extract `content` from the above given json data.

```
var result = jsonPath(data, "$.query.results[*].ul.li[*].a.strong.content");
```

Now I am getting the output data as expected.